# php-fpm using more memory than mod_php

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, php5, memory-usage

I recently moved a PHP5 application from Apache 2.4 + mod_php to Apache 2.4 + php-fpm.  Apache is configured to proxy all *.php requests to php-fpm over Unix Domain Sockets. The application required that the php settings increased the memory limit to 384MB, which was the case when using mod_php and that setting is retained under php-fpm.

After the switch to php-fpm, some requests are consuming about 1GB of memory before being killed by the linux OOM.  The same requests in mod_php did not consume the same amount of memory and were therefore not killed.

Note that I've downtuned apache's event mpm to only 2 processes and 8 threads each.  PHP-FPM's pm is set to ondemand and only 2 processes.  I can see that only this request is being executed at that time.  The php-fpm process memory continues to increase steadily to 1GB and gets killed before it can return.

My questions are:
1) Why is php-fpm going past the php.ini memory_limit setting of 384MB? 
2) If apache is proxying to php-fpm using a unix domain socket, then does flushing the buffer even matter? I assume no.
3) Do you have recommendation to troubleshoot and fix this issue?

Comment: Upgrade to a supported version of PHP. Your PHP version is far past end of life, and probably is not supportable by anyone.

Comment: The base OS is CentOS with the PHP5 from their updates repository.  The maintainers of RHEL backport fixes for PHP5 as per their maintenance policy, which CentOS uses verbatim. Also, switching versions of PHP on an application is not trivial and can cause issues.  If it was up to me, I would change it.

Comment: You can only be sure to get security fixes, bug fixes are usually not included. It's never been a good idea to use the PHP version included with RHEL/CentOS (prior to 8, which finally has a workable system for distributing multiple software versions and a more reasonable support policy for fast-moving software).

Comment: Agreed, RHEL only backports security and critical bug fixes. However, I cannot magically port an application from PHP5 to PHP7 that was under development for *years* before my arrival without experiencing significant issues with the code. Also, php7-fpm doesn't guarantee a resolution to the memory issue I'm experiencing unless you have an issue # tracker that suggests this was fixed in php7-fpm. I can give it a shot and hope for the best but it will still need extensive testing of the code, which will take weeks.  That's in the plans for this applications, but you missed the issue at hand.

Comment: I did not miss the issue at hand. I have been addressing it this whole time. It's unreasonable to expect bug fixes for an ancient PHP version that is past EOL. I'm trying to convey to you that it is unlikely you will be able to get support for this issue from anyone until after you upgrade to an in-support PHP release and then find that you are still having the problem. If that takes several weeks, then you'll have to live with the problem for several weeks.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: "I have been addressing it this whole time." No, you didn't. You simply insisted on your view being the only reasonable one. However, OP legitimately hoped for someone else possibly having seen and remembering this problem from the past and knowing something useful that could *mitigate* the burden of living with that legacy codebase. OP obviously knew that it was obsolete, so your "addressing" the trivial fact added no information.

Comment: So I tried Michael Hampton's suggestion to upgrade to PHP7 but it did not solve the problem in any fashion.It turns out I was mistaken about mod_php not consuming as much memory as php-fpm; it was consuming just as much.

Comment: Hopefuly someone finds this useful if they stumble on the same issue.  As per my original questions, here are the answers: 1) This terrible application code was requesting an entire database table to be returned, which doesn't seem to count towards the 384MB php.ini memory limit while it's being streamed back from the database.  I don't know why that's the case though.  2) No, Unix Domain Sockets don't need buffer flushing - adding the option actually makes no difference. 3) Turn on the debugger and step through the code while monitoring the php process/stack